# mounting hard drive that is passed to VM

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, hard-drive, proxmox, e2fsck

I'm running proxmox and I was previously passing a hard drive (ext4 data drive) as iSCSI to a linux VM. Everything was good. Then I decided to pass the PCI SATA controller to the VM instead of just the hard drive. Now I am unable to mount the drive. It says that the structure needs cleaning. e2fsck says the drive is clean, but if I do -f (force) it says "HTREE directory inode 47710209 has an invalid root node." I exited out of that without letting it make any changes since I am not sure if that will mess things up.

So should this have worked, or am I trying something crazy? Anyway to get this to work? I know the drive is fine, and the data should be there. It seems to me like this should be similar to moving a drive from one system to another.